# Poisson vs. Exponential distirbution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

What is the relationship between **Poisson** and **Exponential** distribution ?
How can I obtain one from the other ?

Comment: One is a discrete random variable, the other is continuous. Example of Poisson - number of cars in a left-turn lane in a given interval. Example of exponential - The amount of time needed to wait for a car to appear in the left-turn lane.

Comment: There are  lot of connections, but the main one is that in a *[Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)* with rate $\lambda$, the gap between events has an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ while the number of events in time interval length $t$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda t$.  You can use this to generate Poisson random variables from exponential random variables

Comment: @Henry Do you mean "mean $\lambda t$ or rather parameter $\lambda t$ ? How can I technically generate Poisson from exponential ?

Comment: If you want a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$, generate enough exponential random variables with rate $\lambda$ (alternatively with rate $1$) until their cumulative sum first exceeds $1$ (alternatively first exceeds $\lambda$).  Subtract $1$ from the number of exponential random variables you needed and that is your Poisson random variable.

Comment: Incidentally, I say "mean" and "rate" rather than just "parameter", as I find this less confusing, especially when the same distribution can have different parametrisations.  But here the "mean" and "rate" are indeed parameters of the relevant distribution families

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by saying that the same distribution  can have different parametrisations ?

Comment: @user122424 For example you can parametrise an exponential distribution by its rate, or its mean, or even its median (i.e. half-life) or something else.    You can parametrise a geometric distribution by the probability of success or the probability of failure, and so on.